# Testing Python app which does HTTP requests

Tags: python, unit-testing

For testing I use pytest so it would be great if you suggest something pytest specific.

I have some code which uses the `requests` library. What it does is basically simple POST/GET requests for logging in, parsing data, etc.

Surely I want to test that code locally without doing any actual HTTP requests.

A `monkeypatch` funcarg could be the solution, but I think that mocking `request.get(...)` calls or directly pythons's `urllib` isn't good, because, for example, there are functions which do more than one HTTP request inside , so I can't just mock the `request.get("anyURL")` with a simple `lambda *args, **kwaargs: """<html>response</html>"""`.

There are different URLs which should return different content. Sometimes it should be based on POST/GET data. Also I have no idea how will `requests.session` behave in case of direct mocking. Besides that how to emulate session termination? How to emulate a connection failure?

So in the end in my opinion it's quite hard to use monkey patching here. At least I am not able to write a good mocking function which will take into account everything. Also if I choose to mock `urllib` directly and someday `requests` library starts using something different all my tests will fail.

So the best way I think is to use actual HTTP server which turns on on a test run, and if possible takes into account pytest's scopes, etc (so it's a funcarg). While googling I found only two solutions:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-localserver
- https://github.com/kevin1024/pytest-httpbin

The first one sets up the HTTP server and serves predefined content over a specific URL. Definitely that does not work for me, because as I mentioned some functions which I intend to test do several requests so all inner HTTP `requests.get()` will get the same answer. Bad.

The second one as far a I see has the same problem. Or at least do not understand how to use it.

The third option could be writing a small Flask based service, but I guess  I'll run into a problem that things I use in tests should be tested as well which is a bad practice.

Comment: I think that use `unittest.mock` (or `mock` for python pre 3.4) for patching and mocking `urllib.requests()` is exactly what you need: you can test if your app call it correctly and the behavior on `requests()` return values.

Comment: I mentioned the monkeypatch funcarg which is almost the same as unittest.mock. All the problems with it are described in a topic. Does not seems as a solution.

Comment: IMHO if you are speaking about unit test (and not integration test) is better is you trust `urllib` and mock it even if it do several request (you can use `side_effect` property of mocks objects to play with that cases). If you try to test your application by mock the server you will have a lot of issue to track your bugs because your sense points will be too far from your bugs. Sure, you need even integration tests that use real server and real `urllib` calls but not for all your expected behaviors. You are free to experiment to mock the server but i think you will know the awful truth :)

Comment: @Michele d'Amic Maybe you are right and my unittests are more integrational tests but anyhow you call it I should test this app . Unfortunetly pytest's monkeypatch does not have a side effect feature. And even if it did there is to much I need to take into account while writing a patching function. I hoped somebody faced this problem and wrote a library which does _mocking_ as you suggest but it includes per-URL side effect so to speak.

Comment: A per-URL `side_effect` is very simple to do: please spend 2 minutes to read the documentation http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect . Write a callable that map a dictionary do the work. You can use `mock` as is without unittest.

Answer (score 1):

You can rather unmock `get` after first call.

```
class Requester():
    def get(*args):
         ...

def mock_get(requester, response):
    orig_get = requester.get
    def return_text_and_unmock(*args, **kwargs):
        self.get = orig_get
        return response
    requester.get = return_text_and_unmock.__get__(requester, Requester)
    return requester
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem. For example a website has a 'delete' link, which redirects you to a confirmation page. So in a function `def delete(...)` you do POST on url1, then second POST on url2.  Also you have to take into account a token in a form, etc ... Your solution will perform second get request to the actual webserver. Also will it keep requests.session consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using a local server for *unit testing* is not a good idea as this is not really a *unit test*. I you're using `requests` one good way of being able to mock the requests is to use the module `responses` that is developed and maintained by dropbox: [response dropbox](https://github.com/dropbox/responses). With `responses` you will be able to mock each request you make by specifying that you want a certain content to be return when a request is issued to a given URL. The README gives a quick overview of the module's abilities.

Comment: Why isn't that a unit testing? When you test an arbitrary Add function which calculates  something, then adds it to the database. You will set up a mysql server and put assert on "SELECT ... FROM tbl" or something like that I guess.
Thanks to 'responses' I'll take a look.

Comment: IMHO if you have to setup a local server or have a database running that's an *integration* test as you are testing something outside of your code, something you are responsible for. Using `responses ` will reduce the scope of the test to something you can control.

Comment: I'm not sure what benefits Dropbox's Responses have over HTTPretty though.

Comment: From what I just read on HTTPretty I would say nothing :). My answer was `responses` specific because it is the python package I use and I've never heard of HTTPretty before.